# Text effect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created the notification bar with the text effect everything seems ok but when i add the text effect like moving from left to right in that it seems work when in first time and after that it looks like this way see the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/UCTgR/10/)**

```
 jQuery('.text').animate({
                'right': '300px'
            }, 'slow', 'linear').animate({
                'left': '300px'
            }, 'slow', 'linear').animate({
                'left': '0',
                'right': '0',
            });
```

For the second time when i click expand it appears from center to right when i refreshing the page itself it appear properly for the first time.

Is there is a way to show the message as from left to right to center whenever i open the bar.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('.text').animate({
                'right': '300px',
            }, 'slow', 'linear').animate({
                'left': '300px'
            }, 'slow', 'linear').animate({
                'left': '0',
                'right': '0',
            });
    jQuery('.text').css('right', 'auto')
    jQuery('.text').css('left', 'auto')
});
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/UCTgR/12/ (Note: this demo has partial functionality yo just show what u missed, to check click on the banner)